# Rascal meta-model

Tags: version-control, bug-tracking, metamodel, rascal

Does Rascal meta-model include representation of version control system information and bug tracker info similarly to [the one advocated for FAMIX](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1571066105001416) by Antoniol *et al.*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No not like the link you provided, there exists the Rascal MSR project `https://github.com/cwi-swat/rascal-msr` which allows one to extract SVN, GIT and perhaps CVS models for a repository. This is based on this masters thesis:  [Rminer: An integrated model for repository mining using Rascal : A feasibility study](http://dare.uva.nl/document/199508), and provides a direct mapping of all meta-data in these repositories to Rascal with a common core representation.

Ashim Shahi has made some progress on adding version information to M3 models, and there exist M3 diff tools generated by the students of the software evolution course at UvA: https://github.com/ruudvanderweijde/EvolutionAdvancedTrack